# Explain the proof of proposition (3.4) of Gerald B. Folland "A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis" book

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Please explain the specified phrase in more details:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You asked a question before in similar style as you've done here. We *cannot* help you if you do not explain what you do not understand which you seem not to either understand or care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v \in M^\bot$, then $Pv=0$, since $P$ is the orthogonal projection on $M$.

Further, Proposition (3.1) shows that $M^\bot$ is invariant under each $\pi(x)$. Hence, $\pi(x)v \in M^\bot$. With the same argument as above, we get $P \pi(x)v=0$.